# Building a functioning Assimp.exe?

Tags: dll, exe, assimp

I've built Assimp 3.1.1 with CMake and Visual Studio 2013. I have both the .dll and the .exe (the .dll is fine), however, using Dependency Walker, these errors show up for the .exe:

[image]

What is going wrong here? Is it an error with the build itself? Does anyone have a working Assimp.exe available for download, if there is no appropriate action I can take to fix this?